# HTML, CSS, JS Unexpected end of input error

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, compiler-errors

I am working on a card game but I am getting this error, unexpected end of input. I know nothing about this error so any help would be appreciated. The [codepen](https://codepen.io/Shadowunicorn1/pen/pPdajL) is also not displaying anything and it is giving the error as well as the compiler in StackOverflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var turn = true;

var enemyCards = document.getElementById('enemy-cards');

var friendlyCards = document.getElementById('friendly-cards');

var friendlyHealth = document.getElementById('friendly-health-value');

var enemyHealth = document.getElementById('enemy-health-value');

var goodHealth=20;
var badHealth=20;

var enemyCardArray = [[2, 3], [2, 4]];

var friendlyCardArray = [[4, 3], [3,2]];

function initialSetup() {
  for (var i=0; i < enemyCardArray.length; i++) {
    var card = enemyCardArray[i]
    var damage = card[0];
    var health = card[1];
    enemyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>"+damage+"</h1><h1 class='health'>"+health+"</h1></div>"
  }

  for (var i=0; i < friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
    var card = friendlyCardArray[i]
    var damage = card[0];
    var health = card[1];
    friendlyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>"+damage+"</h1><h1 class='health'>"+health+"</h1></div>"
  }
}

function setup() {
       enemyCards.innerHTML = "";//<--Set it to "" here, not in for loop
       friendlyCards.innerHTML = "";//<--Set it to "" here, not in for loop
       for (var i = 0; i < enemyCardArray.length; i++) {
            var card = enemyCardArray[i]
            var damage = card[0];
            var health = card[1];
            //enemyCards.innerHTML = "";
            enemyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>" + damage + "</h1><h1 class='health'>" + health + "</h1></div>";
                }

       for (var i = 0; i < friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
              var card = friendlyCardArray[i]
              var damage = card[0];
              var health = card[1];
              //friendlyCards.innerHTML = "";
              friendlyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>" + damage + "</h1><h1 class='health'>" + health + "</h1></div>";
                }
            }

function battle() {
  if (turn === true){
    for (var i = 0; i<friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
      if (friendlyCardArray.length == enemyCardArray.length){
        enemyCardArray[i][1] -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
        if (enemyCardArray[i][1] < 1){
          enemyCardArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }if(friendlyCardArray.length>enemyCardArray.length){
        for (var i=0; i<enemyCardArray.length; i++){
          enemyCardArray[i][1] -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
        if (enemyCardArray[i][1] < 1){
          enemyCardArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
       }
        for (var i=enemyCardArray.length+1; i>enemyCardArray.length; i++){
          badHealth-=friendlyCardArray[i][0];
          if (i == frienlyCardArray.length+1){
            break;
          }
        }
        
      }if(friendlyCardArray.length<enemyCardArray.length){
        for (var i=0; i<friendlyCardArray.length; i++){
          enemyCardArray[i][1] -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
        if (enemyCardArray[i][1] < 1){
          enemyCardArray.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
        
  }if (turn === false){
    
  }
}
initialSetup();
battle();
setup();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

#enemy-cards{
  background-color: #873a00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
}

#friendly-cards{
  background-color: #873a00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

.damage {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 20px;
}

.health {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right: 20px;
}

#friendly-health{
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
}
#friendly-health-value{
  position: fixed;
  left: 25%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}

#enemy-health-value{
  position: fixed;
  left: 75%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}

#enemy-health{
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #f73f27;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div id="enemy-cards">
  </div>
  <div id="health">
    <div id="friendly-health">
      <h1 id="friendly-health-value">20</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="enemy-health">
      <h1 id="enemy-health-value">20</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="friendly-cards">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` somewhere in your `battle()` function

Comment: Nope he is missing 2 `}` in the end of his last function. :)

Comment: `battle()` IS the last function, isn't it? Not necessarily in the end, depends on how all those `for` loops and `if` statements are supposed to be nested :)

Comment: if you properly indent your code, it will be much easier, for you and everybody looking at yor code, to find the misplaced braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Your Js

```
var turn = true;

var enemyCards = document.getElementById('enemy-cards');

var friendlyCards = document.getElementById('friendly-cards');

var friendlyHealth = document.getElementById('friendly-health-value');

var enemyHealth = document.getElementById('enemy-health-value');

var goodHealth = 20;
var badHealth = 20;

var enemyCardArray = [
    [2, 3],
    [2, 4]
];

var friendlyCardArray = [
    [4, 3],
    [3, 2]
];

function initialSetup() {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemyCardArray.length; i++) {
        var card = enemyCardArray[i];
        var damage = card[0];
        var health = card[1];
        enemyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>" + damage + " <
            /h1><h1 class='health'>"+health+"</h
        1 > < /div>"
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
        var card = friendlyCardArray[i];
        var damage = card[0];
        var health = card[1];
        friendlyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>" + damage + " <
            /h1><h1 class='health'>"+health+"</h
        1 > < /div>"
    }
}

function setup() {
    enemyCards.innerHTML = ""; //<--Set it to "" here, not in for loop
    friendlyCards.innerHTML = ""; //<--Set it to "" here, not in for loop
    for (var i = 0; i < enemyCardArray.length; i++) {
        var card = enemyCardArray[i];
        var damage = card[0];
        var health = card[1];
        //enemyCards.innerHTML = "";
        enemyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>" +
            damage + "</h1><h1 class='health'>" + health + "</h1></div>";
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
        var card = friendlyCardArray[i];
        var damage = card[0];
        var health = card[1];
        //friendlyCards.innerHTML = "";
        friendlyCards.innerHTML += "<div class='card'><h1 class='damage'>" +
            damage + "</h1><h1 class='health'>" + health + "</h1></div>";
    }
}

function battle() {
    if (turn === true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
            if (friendlyCardArray.length == enemyCardArray.length) {
                enemyCardArray[i][1] -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
                if (enemyCardArray[i][1] < 1) {
                    enemyCardArray.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            if (friendlyCardArray.length > enemyCardArray.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < enemyCardArray.length; i++) {
                    enemyCardArray[i][1] -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
                    if (enemyCardArray[i][1] < 1) {
                        enemyCardArray.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
                for (var i = enemyCardArray.length + 1; i > enemyCardArray.length; i++) {
                    badHealth -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
                    if (i == frienlyCardArray.length + 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (friendlyCardArray.length < enemyCardArray.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < friendlyCardArray.length; i++) {
                    enemyCardArray[i][1] -= friendlyCardArray[i][0];
                    if (enemyCardArray[i][1] < 1) {
                        enemyCardArray.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }

            }
            if (turn === false) {

            }
        }
    }
}
initialSetup();
battle();
setup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) & [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) It Will Show Your Mistakes & Warnings. Hope It Helps You.